# SSH ec2 goes to private IP

Tags: ssh, aws

I have an ec2 instance on AWS that has an EIP associated and is accessible via SSH (usually). Not sure what changed between yesterday and today but now I cant SSH into the server directly from my PC. This is what happens:

1. When I SSH to the server (say foo), I get:

   ```
   debug1: Connecting to foo [10.0.0.55] port 22.
   debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.55 port 22: Connection refused
   ssh: connect to host foo port 22: Connection refused
   ```
2. When I run host foo, it resolves to the correct EIP and domain:

   ```
   foo.bar.net has address 34.204.x.x
   ```

I know one solution is to either add an entry into `/etc/hosts` or to adjust my `~/.ssh/config` and add the `.bar.net` to the host's entry. I don't want to do either or. My question is, what can I do aside from these two solutions to make sure that SSH points to the EIP instead of it's internal IP? Just an FYI, my PC I am using is Mac OSX.

Comment: Perhaps see if your ssh key is still there (`ls -al ~/.ssh`) locally  and whether t is still recognized by AWS ?

Comment: One of the first things i checked.. its not a key issue

Comment: What is an "EIP"? External IP? And there is something wrong on your local computer if it is pointing to 10.0.0.55. What's at 10.0.0.55? What's in /etc/hosts? What happens when you try to SSH to your server's FQDN?

Comment: EIP = elastic IP, and sorry but i wanted to give random IPs not the actual IPs

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` doesn't "point to" anything, unless you specifically set that up in `.ssh/config` .

Also note that the `host` command specifically uses DNS to look up names, and will not check your `/etc/hosts` file.

Something in your machine's configuration is relating a host named "foo" to that IP address.  Is it in your `/etc/hosts` file?  Maybe your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file is doing something unusual and pulling "foo" from an LDAP or NIS server?

What do you get if you `ping foo` or `nc -v foo 22` ?

Comment: I ended up using HostName in my config so it can resolve correctly.. still remains a mystery.. i couldnt find anything that points to the wrong IP